# Почему не срабатывает часть кода?

Tags: c#, sql

Есть такой код:

```
 if (statusAccGoldOrBase.Text == "базовый") {
     cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE t_links SET balance = balance - '" + statusbase + "' WHERE URL= '" + URL + "'";
     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE t_user SET balance = balance + '" + statusbase + "' WHERE username='" + textUserName.Text + "' and pass='" + Convert.ToString(textPassword.Text) + "'";
     cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Код cmd срабатывает, а вот cmd2 нет... Хотя вроде сделано все правильно.

Comment: а как вы определили что не срабатывает? если ничего не обновляет видимо ни одна строка не соответствует условиям выборки

Comment: Да вот именно ничего не обновляет... а почему не знаю, вроде все верно.

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно проблема в "'" - этот символ обычно используется для строк. У вас же balance, судя по всему, - это числовое поле.

1. cmd2: set balance = balance - 'statusbase' --> number = number - string
2. cmd: set balance = balance + 'string' --> number = number + string

Возможно, cmd отрабатывает (не уверен, что правильно), потому что сначала balance неявно конвертируется к типу string, после чего к значению в конец добавляется строка (предполагаем, в вашей БД "+"  - функция конкатенации строк) 'statusbase' результат неявно конвертируется к типу number. Функции "-" для строк нет.

Comment: я предлагаю вывести на экран строку для cmd и cmd2 и выполнить их как посоветовал @alvin. а потом попробовать выполнить их без критерии where.

Answer (score 4):

Может быть просто по указанной URL ничего не находит? Например у вас в бд хранятся ссылки типа "http://www...." а вы передаёте параметр "www...". Попробуйте выполнить запрос не из кода а напрямую через Database Engine/Server explorer